# Python socket recv waits for send if using getch?

Tags: python, python-sockets

This is a very unexpected behavior:

Here is a textbook classic short program that uses one thread to get characters one by one from a socket stream and display it, and a second thread to read input and send the input over the same socket stream.

import socket
    import threading
    import getch
    import sys

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

def rxWorker():
    while(True):
        r = s.recv(1)
        print(r.decode('ascii'), end='')

def txWorker():
    while (True):
        i = input('')
        s.send(i.encode())

s.connect(('localhost',9999))

threading.Thread(name='Rx', target=rxWorker).start()
threading.Thread(name='Tx', target=txWorker).start()
```

This works against netcat listener that is running is a different terminal:

```
nc -l localhost 9999
```

At this point everything works well. Lines are sent from side to side and appear as expected.

Now the input is changed to immediate, so the python side  sends characters as they are typed (not waiting for a newline), like so:

import socket
    import threading
    import getch
    import sys

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

def rxWorker():
    while(True):
        r = s.recv(1)
        print(r.decode('ascii'), end='')

def txWorker():
    while (True):
        # i = input('')
        i = getch.getche()
        s.send(i.encode())

s.connect(('localhost',9999))

threading.Thread(name='Rx', target=rxWorker).start()
threading.Thread(name='Tx', target=txWorker).start()
```

Note that the only change is the way the input is read:                    `i = getch.getche()` vs `i = input('')`

Now the behavior is different.

Characters from the python side appear at the netcat side correctly and immediately.

The problem: character from the netcat side now do not show at the python side immediately.
Thy actually do not show until one or several characters are sent from python to netcat.

This is very strange and kind of breaks my control flow/:

Please advise

System: Ubuntu 16.04 , python 3.5.2

Comment: Done some changes to sample code according to abarnert's notes. problem, persists as described.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you haven't actually enabled `TCP_NODELAY`.

This line does not do what you think it does:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.TCP_NODELAY )
```

The arguments to [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) are:

> ```
> socket.socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None)
> ```

It just so happens that, at least on *nix systems, `TCP_NODELAY` is `1`, and `SOCK_STREAM` is an enum with value `1`, so by passing `TCP_NODELAY` as the type you're selecting `SOCK_STREAM`, aka TCP. When a future version of the `socket` library switches to using enums for `sockopt` values (as it already does for the types), this will become a `TypeError` instead of silently doing something unexpected that occasionally happens to sort of work.

If you want to enable a `sockopt` value like `TCP_NODELAY`, you have to call [`setsockopt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt) on the socket. Like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

---

As a side note, there's at least one other obvious error in your code, although it isn't causing any problems:

```
rxt = threading.Thread(name='Rx', target=rxWorker).start()
```

`Thread.start` returns `None`. So you're seeing `rxt` (and `txt`) to `None`. Fortunately, you don't actually do anything with them—but as soon as you do, e.g., `rxt.join()`, you're going to get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

I changed the question according to the comments to make the question more clear.

Unfortunately the problem is not related to the flags and still persists.